# OpenBSD how to Create node for wd1 block device?

Tags: openbsd

On OpenBSD, during install:
Via `dmesg | grep wd1 -A1` I know this information:

> ```
> wd1 at pciide0 channel 0 drive 1: <VBOX HARDDISK>
> wd1 128-sector PIO, LBA, 450MB, 922496 sectors
> ```

however I cannot find the block device in `/dev`

`ls /dev | grep wd1`

It seems that this might be because the node `mknode` needs to be created still. How can I go about this?

which information do I need to use `mknode` for the `wd1` block device?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am not certain about which kernel I booted. at the initial occurence of the string `boot:` I only hit enter. I used the most recently acquired install66.fs file as basis for my install. I was able to (see the answer below) to get the `wd1` block device files in `/dev` . Maybe you can confirm even that the way to get it was correct?

Comment: If you're booting from `bsd.rd` (the install/update kernel), the appropriate device files will be installed automatically once you have reached the stage in the installation process that detects the disks.  If you boot `bsd.rd` and immediately drop into a shell, then yes, the device files for the available disks may not be there.

Comment: Are you doing something _special_ on your `wd1` disk, or did the installation simply not allow you to access that disk?

Comment: @Kusalananda I guess I assumed that the included "sets" would be on a already mounted and `mknod`ed place. So I might have replied `yes` in the tui when it asked about the "sets" being already at a mounted place. I then used `Ctrl-Z` to briefly background the install and search for the 6.6/amd64 directory. Probably this was however a way to have the install not have the device file created, neither the devices mounted, maybe?

Comment: Hmm... When you're installing from `install66.iso` (the CD image), which I usually do on VirtualBox, the install sets are on the `cd0` device.

Answer (score 0):

as `man mknod` shows there is a script at `/dev/MAKEDEV`. In my specific case therefore I did this

```
chmod u+x /dev/MAKEDEV
/dev/MAKEDEV wd1
```

which provoked a whole set of new block device files being created alls starting with `wd1` in `/dev`

Comment: The `MAKEDEV` script should already be executable, unless you've previously changed the permissions on it.